How should I explain to people why I left my previous law job?
I was working at one of the magic circle firms, but I began experiencing significant challenges after I went off my SSRIs, which I'd been on in high doses for years. The withdrawal symptoms were intense, and combined with the stress of my job, they led to me failing all six of my certificate-level exams. I felt too ill to turn up for work and struggled to perform my responsibilities properly.
During this difficult period, I was diagnosed with autism, PTSD, depression, and anxiety. My parents advised me not to disclose my mental health issues to future employers, so I only told my boss about my autism diagnosis and kept the rest to myself. My boss was skeptical and angry, questioning whether my autism alone could explain my struggles. He even accused me of lying, saying my autism didn’t seem severe enough to cause all the problems I was experiencing. However, he did follow the Disability Discrimination Act 2010 procedure and gave me another chance.
I was then sent to Wakefield to work in a credit control role, which involved making 25 calls a day, writing emails to angry customers, and liaising with a difficult client whose account management department was quite challenging. Unfortunately, this role heavily relied on social and communication skills, which are areas where I struggle due to my autism. I made several mistakes, like canceling the wrong contracts, deleting files, accidentally CCing internal emails to customers, and even asking the client's CFO if he would renew a contract, which didn’t go over well.
On top of that, my boss was frustrated with me for missing timesheets, taking long PTOs, and working from home. Eventually, he suggested that I leave the company. I decided it would be better to resign, and he agreed, likely to avoid any potential legal issues for the company.
Obviously, I can't explain to the next employer why I really left bc who would want to employ someone so ill? What do I say? I only lasted 10 months.

You need to add a location tag. It sounds like the UK but I'm not sure. It would also help to give an overview over your total work  history. If you already have significant work experience a single 10-month "wasn't a good fit" isn't much of a concern.

@Hilmar Magic circle and Wakefield is definitely UK.

Focus on getting well, finding a good doctor who will monitor your progress and modify your medication when necessary. Get a job in a pet or florist store where the working hours never, if rarely, change. I don't know, think what skills you have and how you can prioritise them. You'll earn less money but being smart you'll know how to successfully budget.

I'll go along with @Hilmar.  "It wasn't a good fit" and maybe add "...they had me liaising with some difficult clients, something I am not good at."  Tell the truth, just don't feel compelled to tell the whole absolute unvarnished truth.  Something like "I was having difficulties," they don't need medical details.  In the US, most companies will only say when you worked there, not anything about how you performed, for better or worse.

SSRI = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_serotonin_reuptake_inhibitor (I had to look it up so I guess others might too)

This is a XY problem. Your main concern is to address your health problems, not to conceal hard-to-conceal information.
You already have the experience that keeping your condition secret is not really possible. So you can be upfront and tell the truth. They are going to find it out anyway.
If you keep trying to get into jobs where you are not suitable, you risk building a bad reputation, which will not be easy to clean. It is much better to be upfront about your condition and about the treatment you follow, rather than ruin your reputation. Many of the the hiring managers are actually kind people, which faced such problems before (themselves, or people they know) - and might even be able to help you with some advice.

who would want to employ someone so ill?

You are right, but only partially. Nobody asks you to go to any extreme. You tried the extreme of keeping things 100% secret. Do not jump to tell 100% the entire story. When I was asked why I went from a project management job back to engineering, my answer was something like:

The project that I managed was quite difficult because (some of the reasons), and I needed a temporary relaxation time. That is why I decided to return to the specialist / expert position of (what I was doing).

I did not hide the mental tiredness, but I did not reveal the exact situation and the exact problems either.
You need to find your own good middle way to navigate the issues, depending on all the details of your situation.

Out of curiosity, wouldn't a future employer normally ask for references? In the OP's case, it would look suspicious if he/she left his/her former employer's name out. Maybe in your case you worked for several years without any issue and then hit a hard painful period, a former employer would, we hope, be objective. I'm not sure if an employee of mine who messed up contracts, deleted files, performed poorly with clients over the phone,  CCed internal emails etc. in just ten months would be one I would even consider writing a letter of recommendation.

I asked corporate about this and they told me all references are neutral: it's just date to date, then my position

Yes, company references these days are generally neutral confirmation of dates. Personal references are a different animal

@Mari-LouA: "left... former employer's name out" - yes, that would be suspicious. But it would be less suspicious if OP said something like: "I left my previous employer because my health problems prevented me from meeting the expectations." Now of course, that opens another can of worms - but the exact wording can the decided only by OP - they know all the details.


my SSRIs, which I'd been on in high doses for years. The withdrawal symptoms were intense, ... During this difficult period, I was diagnosed with autism, PTSD, depression, and anxiety.

So you'd been on SSRIs for years, but only after they were stopped were you diagnosed with anxiety and depression? Is there a possibility this sequence of events is the wrong way around?
Also, I don't want to pry, but a question that occurs to me is "why was the medication stopped and not resumed?". Here is not the right place to answer such medical questions, but it's something that immediately doesn't seem to make sense.

He even accused me of lying

The man obviously had a good nose for these things. By your own account, you weren't being upfront.

I made several mistakes, like canceling the wrong contracts, deleting files, accidentally CCing internal emails to customers, and even asking the client's CFO if he would renew a contract, which didn’t go over well.

Occasional mistakes are to be expected, and information systems with poor usability can exacerbate error, but lawyers also have to be very precise and careful.

Obviously, I can't explain to the next employer why I really left bc who would want to employ someone so ill? What do I say? I only lasted 10 months.

With the exam failures also, are you sure you have the underlying competence for your chosen occupation? Do you have a record of easy achievement from which you are now deviating only due to illness?
If there isn't another explanation for the illness, then I'd be considering whether your chosen occupation is wearing you down and making you ill. Law is not what it was 40 years ago, and young workers are under relentless assault from employers with poor wages and poor systems of training and skills reproduction.
Trying a different sector could be an option. But if you've become so seriously ill, are you actually capable of working? There's very little you can say if you're simply not fit for work.

While this is an obvious attempt to answer, it does not really come close to answering. It more like a long list of questions. Will you please highlight the part which answers OP's question (at least partially)?

@virolino, there's too little information to give a decisive answer. The OP asked what to say to a new prospective employer, but I think two key points were that the OP should consider whether it's the work itself that is making him ill, and secondly that seeking some verbal formula is not going to solve an incapability issue (which the OP seems to acknowledge, by saying he is "so ill", so it sounds like more than
just a temporary hiccup).

I feel that there are some shades there between your answer (mostly questions) and "some verbal formula" (magic final answer).

@virolino, I'm not expecting the OP would be struggling to understand the thinking points, and I don't want to cut back anything that might be useful for the OP to consider as part of the whole piece.

@Steve Thank you for helping me. I have had some work experience in law firms before such as internships but I have always had good feedback. I also went to oxbridge to finish my law degree with a first. I don't know what happened. Yes, I was originally diagnosed with PTSD before and was put on the ssris.

You have a medical condition that needs to be monitored and treated. Current evidence from what you have said is that going off the SSRI was a mistake, especially if you dropped it suddenly, since there can be rebound effects.
